# Python : How to check if a variable is equal to '' ''

Tags: python

I have a variable:

```
exchange_name = ''
```

Now I want to perform some operation based on checking if it is equal to an empty string.

So, I do:

```
if exchange_name == '':
  # perform some operation
```

But how can I generalize the solution so that `exchange_name` can contain any number of spaces, e.g.:

```
exchange_name = ' '
```

or

```
exchange_name = '  '
```

Can anybody suggest an approach? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You just need to trim white space from your variable and compare that result to the empty string. The strip function will do this for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
exchange_name.strip()==''
```

strip removes all empty spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use rstrip to remove spaces from begin and end of string.

```
if mytext.rstrip() == '':
    do_it()
```